# Proving or disproving existential quantification

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have to prove or disprove this existential quantification:

$\exists x(p(x) \vee q (x)) \Leftrightarrow (\exists xp(x) \vee \exists xq(x))$

Could anyone give me any tips how to proceed or at least how to start? I havent solved them for a long time so I got a bit rusty. Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. You are encouraged to learn to use latex / mathjax formatting. Also if it looks like a hoemwork question you are encouraged to show any work you have tried in solving the problem.

Comment: What does prove mean here? Is arguing about models enough, or does one need to argue within a formal system? They vary, a lot, though they are all equivalent.

Comment: The one who gave this problem just told us that we need to prove that it is true or disprove that. I remember that it can be proved using sets but i do not know how to start.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is actually true. For the forward conditional, start by assuming the left hand side. We know there exists something, call it $a$, such that either $p(a)$ is true or $q(a)$ is true. If $p(a)$ is true, then we know there exists something ($a$) such that p is true, or in symbols, $\exists x p(x)$. Similarly, if $q(a)$ is true, we know $\exists x q(x)$ is true. Since at least one of these two cases must happen, we know that $\exists x p(x)$ or $\exists x q(x)$ is true, as desired.

For the backward conditional, start by assuming the right hand side. Either $\exists x p(x)$ or $\exists x q(x)$ is true. If $\exists x p(x)$ is true, then we know there exists something, call it $a$, such that $p(a)$ is true, implying that $p(a) \vee q(a)$ is true, meaning that $\exists x (p(x) \vee q(x))$, as desired. Otherwise, we have that $\exists x q(x)$ is true, and the results follows similarly.